# Call to undefined method Builder::only()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

For some reason, I am getting an error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::only()

Basically get entries from the database and only get specific fields using `only()` collection

```
$canvas = $this->canvasRepo->get(5);

$shapes = $canvas->shapes->each(function($shape) {
   return $shape->only('name', 'height', 'width');
});
```

Comment: In the loops, use `dd($shape);` to check the object info. And append it to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out this is a relationship, so you can't use get().

If you want your query to fetch only specific fields from the database you reference the relationship as a method not a property.

```
$canvas->shapes()->get(['name', 'height', 'width']);
```

but using `$canvas->shapes` as a property will perform the query `SELECT *` and return a collection on which you can use `pluck` or `only`

**Old Answer**

You need to use `get()` before using `only()` or `pluck()` to fetch the data from the database.

```
$canvas = $this->canvasRepo->get(5);

$shapes = $canvas->shapes->each(function($shape) {
   return $shape->get('name', 'height', 'width');
});
```

This will return only the `'name', 'height', 'width'` fields for related shapes, assuming you defined the relationship.

However, it would be better if you use eager loading to avoid n+1 problem.

Comment: This is a Laravel relation, no `get()` function is needed to load this

Comment: Your new updated answer worked but `Old Answer` did not work.

Comment: Glad it did. Please note that this is not efficient  as it will perform separate query in each iteration. So if a canvas has 10 shapes, 10 queries will be executed. And you're pulling 5 canvas, so that mounts to 50 queries. 
Try to eager load the shapes when fetch the canvas in your canvasRepo.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is that how do you know the `only()` method is legal?
In Laravel, there is only one method called `only()`, it is used to retrieve a subset of the input data. [InteractsWithInput#only](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L144)

## Edit

The items of the collection instance `$shapes` would be converted to array while the collection instance initialize, hence you should not use `only()` method. And you can use `array_only()` provied by laravel helpers.

```
$shapes = $canvas->shapes->each(function($shape) {
    return array_only($shape, ['name', 'height', 'width']);
});
```

Comment: `only` is a method from Laravel Collection. Problem is when getting result from the database it is not collection object. That is why I am asking the solution for this.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use `pluck` instead of `only` to get specific field from `table`.

But it's for only one field. so you need to `select` and `get` method.

Try this:

```
$shapes = $canvas->shapes->each(function($shape) {
    return $shape->select('name','height','width');
})->get();
```

Comment: using `pluck` I didn't get any error but show it showing all the fields instead of specific fields.

Comment: This won't work, the second parameter of pluck is the key used for this element. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck

Comment: Sorry, I have forgot about multiple fields, I have updated my answer. This might work. Take a moment to view it.

Comment: No, this is not going to work.  `get()` is already called in the repo